# Переключение источника картинки для монитора

Tags: windows

Есть один монитор - в него воткнуто устройство (в данном случае *Chromecast*) по HDMI, а от компа идет VGA. Возможно ли программно переключаться между портами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В VGA отсутствует какой-либо стандартный интерфейс для выбора источника сигнала. Все, на что способен VGA - определение информации о мониторе (EDID) и управление питанием.

Так что увы - такой возможности нет.

Answer (score 1):

Порт же вы выбираете на мониторе, так что если у монитора есть автовыбор источника сигнала или ни как.